# Python code that upload each url file to an AWS S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-s3, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, aws-lambda

I am new on using s3 and other AWS services, and I am using an android tablet to code (Google Colab)

there is an way to upload all these url's files that are pdf files to an S3 bucket.

I have already tried to use AWS Lambda but I alway get an error when I try to put the bs4 layer to read the bs4 module.

`pip install requests`
`pip install bs4`

```
import requests
import bs4


DOMAIN = "https://www.conab.gov.br"
URL = "https://www.conab.gov.br/info-agro/analises-do-mercado-agropecuario-e-extrativista/analises-do-mercado/historico-de-conjunturas-de-cafe"
filetype ='download'


def get_soup(url):
  return bs4.BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')


for link in get_soup(URL).find_all('a'):
  pdf_link = link.get('href')
  if filetype in pdf_link:
    pdf_file = DOMAIN + pdf_link
    print(pdf_file)
```

Comment: Would you be open to using aws-cli? If so you may be able to call the cli functions using python's subprocess module.

Comment: spo,  do you mean trying to install the modules with the aws-cli?

Comment: If you can install aws-cli you can use commands like `aws s3 cp local.pdf s3://bucket-name/` which will copy local files to the s3 bucket. But given the environment you are working on maybe this will not work. I have never used google colab or coded on android tablet before.

Comment: I am super limited with an android environment, spo.
But thanks for the help, I am looking to connect this code direct with my s3 bucket by using boto3 and access key.
When you learn to code with android you always need multiple choices to properly execute your codes/projects.